# What is the standard deviation of the frequency table below?

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

[image]
Hello, I have some issues with finding the standard deviation of this question.
I found the mean as 337.5 km, and I considered that standard deviation is the root of the variance.
I first squared the frequency to calculate E($X^2$) and subtracted by $mean^2$.
Then I square rooted and got 80.6 km as my variance, but looks like it is wrong. Can someone find my mistake?

Comment: Square the distance, not the frequency.

Comment: oops. That was the mistake. Thank you.

Comment: When I squared the distance, I got a very large number.

Answer (score 1):

$$E(X^2)=\frac{2•50^2+5•150^2+\cdots}{2+5+\cdots}\\
\sigma^2=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2\\
\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma^2}$$

I think $80$km is a reasonable value for $\sigma$

Comment: Oh, ok. I found my mistake. Thank you.